# Stripe API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm trying to use `source_transaction` with the Rails API so that I can have managed accounts that create payments and are later sent to other accounts.

I'm getting the error `Stripe::InvalidRequestError: Insufficient funds in Stripe account. In test mode, you can add funds to your available bal
ance (bypassing your pending balance) by creating a charge with 4000 0000 0000 0077 as the card number.   You can use th
e the /v1/balance endpoint to view your Stripe balance (for more details, see stripe.com/docs/api#balance).`

But usinrg `source_transaction` I thought was supposed to bypass using my balance and only transfer funds once the transaction cleared.

Here is the code I'm using

```
charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer    => stripe_cust_id,
    :amount      => total_amount_owed,
    :description => 'Groundwork Subscription Charge',
    :currency    => 'usd',
    :transfer_group => invoice_number
)

...

transfer = Stripe::Transfer.create({
    :amount => amount_to_transfer,
    :currency => "usd",
    :destination => StripeInfo.where(account_id: project_owner.accounts.first.id).first.stripe_id,
    :application_fee => (amount_to_transfer*0.05).round,
    :source_transaction => charge[:charge_id]
  # :transfer_group => invoice_number
})
```

Comment: Nope.  Not unless it was a Destination Charge (ie. you used the `destination`-argument with the Create a Charge request).

Comment: I'm using `destination` in the transfer because a single payment will be going to multiple destinations. How can I have it bypass my balance while doing this?

Comment: Got it, needed to use `charge.id`

Comment: Hi @Adam12344. I seem to be having the same problem as yourself. Can please you explain where you're using the charge.id call to bypass a balance when trying to transfer single payment to multiple destinations? Thanks a million.

Comment: This is a pretty old project, but looking back at the code I changed the source_transaction: `:source_transaction => charge.id`